# trying to acees static method from 1 class to another

Tags: c++, class, static

I have 3 classes LocationData,PointTwoD and MissionPlan.
Class MissionPlan is my driver class which will run all my programs.
In my LocationData, there is a static method which takes in 5 inputs from the user and it will compute into a float and return the value.
So as said earlier MissionPlan is my driver class, all the inputs will be linked in my MissionPLan class, and i try to do the static method call in MissionPlan to compute the value, LocationData::computeCivIndex(s,i,j,k,l); but it return me a very long error.

**/tmp/ccK8Rwha.o: In function `MissionPlan::MissionPlan()':
test.cpp:(.text+0x9f1): undefined reference to`LocationData::computeCivIndex(std::basic_string, std::allocator >, int, int, float, float)'
/tmp/ccK8Rwha.o: In function `MissionPlan::MissionPlan()':**

**test.cpp:(.text+0xfb7): undefined reference to `LocationData::computeCivIndex(std::basic_string, std::allocator >, int, int, float, float)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**

```
class LocationData
{   
    private:
        //codes for initilization
    public:
    LocationData();
    LocationData(string,int,int,float,float);
    //getter and setter methods..
    static float computeCivIndex(string,int,int,float,float);
};

class MissionPlan
{
    public:
    MissionPlan();
};

static float computeCivIndex(string sunType, int noOfEarthLikePlanets,int     noOfEarthLikemoons, float aveParticulateDensity, float avePlasmaDensity)
{
    LocationData data; //not sure if i need this
        //methods to caculate...
    float ci = 0.0;
        return ci;
}

MissionPlan::MissionPlan()
{
        int choice; // to capture what user inputs into menu
        int count=0; 
            //codes to get user inputs
        cin>>choice;
        for(;;)
        {
        if(choice == 1)
        {       
            int i,j,x,y;
        float k,l;
         string s;
       //codes to get user inputs
        LocationData::computeCivIndex(s,i,j,k,l); //the part where error occurs
         count++;
     }
    else if(choice == 2)
    {
        cout<<"Computation completed!"<<endl;
        break;
    }
    else if(choice==3);
    else if(choice==4);
    else
        cout<<"Please enter number 1 to 4 only!"<<endl;
    }//end of do loop
}//end of MissionPlan()
int main()
{
    MissionPlan plan;
    MissionPlan();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented the static method - you have created another one.

Try this instead:

```
float LocationData::computeCivIndex...
```

in the place where you're implementing it.

Comment: i got an error test.cpp: In constructor ‘MissionPlan::MissionPlan()’:
test.cpp:253: error: invalid use of qualified-name ‘LocationData::computeCivIndex’

Comment: It compiles fine for me. Are you sure you changed the right thing? The class definition should stay the same, the place where you're implementing `computeCivIndex` below `MissionPlan` should be as I showed.

Answer (score 0):

You declared a static method of the class LocationData but never defined it.

Change

```
static float computeCivIndex(string sunType, int noOfEarthLikePlanets,int     noOfEarthLikemoons, float aveParticulateDensity, float avePlasmaDensity)
```

to

```
float LocationData::computeCivIndex(string sunType, int noOfEarthLikePlanets,int     noOfEarthLikemoons, float aveParticulateDensity, float avePlasmaDensity)
```

Comment: i tried adding , and i got this error test.cpp:169: error: cannot declare member function ‘static float LocationData::computeCivIndex(std::string, int, int, float, float)’ to have static linkage

Comment: Oops.. strike the static. Just 
      float LocationData::computeCivIndex(string sunType, int noOfEarthLikePlanets,int     noOfEarthLikemoons, float aveParticulateDensity, float avePlasmaDensity)

Comment: @HengAikHwee Edited my answer to remove the static

Answer (score 0):

Two errors from what you've posted:

```
static float computeCivIndex(string sunType, int noOfEarthLikePlanets,int     noOfEarthLikemoons, float aveParticulateDensity, float avePlasmaDensity)
{
    LocationData data; //not sure if i need this
        //methods to caculate...
    float ci = 0.0;
        return ci;
}
```

This function should be:

```
float LocationData::computeCivIndex(string sunType, int noOfEarthLikePlanets,int     noOfEarthLikemoons, float aveParticulateDensity, float avePlasmaDensity)
{
    LocationData data; //not sure if i need this
        //methods to caculate...
    float ci = 0.0;
        return ci;
}
```

Secondly, I don't know how much this is correct:

in your `main` function: you defined something that doesn't seem right

`MissionPlan();`

You're calling a constructor without an object? Although its valid syntax, and the constructor will be called.. why do it twice?